# How to adjust the size of block.outputport.data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink, clock

I have tried to generate a square pulsed clock. But it gives error. I tried this:

```
function pll( block)

setup(block);

function setup(block)

% Register number of ports
block.NumInputPorts  = 1;
block.NumOutputPorts = 1;


% Override input port properties
block.InputPort(1).Dimensions        = 1;
block.InputPort(1).DatatypeID  = 8;  % boolean
block.InputPort(1).Complexity  = 'Real';
block.InputPort(1).DirectFeedthrough = false;


% Override output port properties

block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions       = 1;
block.OutputPort(1).DatatypeID  = 0; %double
block.OutputPort(1).Complexity  = 'Real';

  block.NumDialogPrms     = 1;
  block.DialogPrmsTunable = 0;
ts = 1/24000000'; %'
block.sample times= [ts 0];
block.SimStateCompliance = 'DefaultSimState'
function Outputs(block)
t = [0:1/(24000000):0.000001];
l = 0.1*exp(-6);

c = 220*exp(-9) + 60*exp(-9);


f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(l*c));

block.OutputPort(1).Data = square(2*pi*f*t);

function Terminate(block)
```

But it gives me the error

> "Error evaluating registered method 'Outputs' of M-S-Function 'pll' in
>   'untitled/Level-2 M-file S-Function'. Invalid assignment in
>   'untitled/Level-2 M-file S-Function': attempt to assign a vector of
>   width 24001 to a vector of width 1."

the error indicates on the line

```
block.OutputPort(1).Data = square(2*pi*f*t);
```

so what can be done to overcome this error?

Comment: This line `block.OutputPort(1).Data = square(2*pift);` does not appear in the posted code

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your example that you're not really familiar with the way Simulink works.  At each time step, each block in a Simulink model outputs a value (i.e the block's output value) corresponding to the ***current*** simulation time.  In your case, within the `block.Output` function you are trying to output ***all*** time points at ***every*** simulation time step.

It appears that what you really want is to replace

```
t = [0:1/(24000000):0.000001];
```

with

```
t = block.CurrentTime;
```

And replace

```
block.OutputPort(1).Data = square(2*pi*f*t);
```

with

```
block.OutputPort(1).Data = sign(sin(2*pi*f*t));
```

Also, some other things to consider:

1. you don't seem to be registering the block's output method using:

   block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs',@Output);
2. Why have you defined the block to have an input when it doesn't seem to require one?
3. Why are you doing this in an S-Function when a From Workspace block (or one of the many other ways to get data into a model) would seem to make more sense?

Comment: thanks phil, i m not much familiar with simout, so i opted for s- function

Comment: and i dont think sign function will help me as my values never goes down below 0.

Comment: My  mistake, is should have been `sign(sin(2*pi*f*t))`.

Comment: yeah Thanks i did the same, by the way i didnt understood block.Currenttime i am not familiar with this. does this consider the sampling time as well?

Comment: No.  It gives the current simulation time.  The sample time determines when the block is called.

Comment: you mean when we define it in ts (block.SampleTimes = [Ts 0];)

Comment: No. I mean if the simulation is current at 10.456 seconds then `block.Currenttime` is 10.456; if the simulation is currently at 67.42 seconds then `block.Currenttime` is 67.42.

Comment: then can we change the simulation time?

Comment: Yes and no.  With the way you've written the S-Function the block tells the solver its sample rate (as you have done) and then the solver calls the block at the appropriate times.  Once the simulation is running that can't be changed.  However, since you have called your function pll (presumably for phase-locked loop) you most likely do need to change the sample rate at each time step.  That is done differently to what you have.  Have a look at the example [Square Wave with jitter](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-sfunction-square-wave-with-jitter.html) to see how to do this.